# Applied Math or Computer Science for graduate school

Tags: career-path

I am a 4th-year student about to finish my math and computer science programs (double major). I have taken both pure math courses and computer science courses and I find myself more interested in math. However, many have told me that computer science may be a better option if I want to find a job in non-academic area.
1. Should I go to graduate for applied math or computer science?
2. Does it matter which path I choose if my ultimate goal is to find a job in the industry, considering I will have a computer science bachelor's degree?
3. Am I going to be ok in graduate school if all the math courses I have taken are pure math

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about "the industry" you want to end up in should play some role in your decision. For some careers applied math would be better than more cs, for some the opposite.

I suggest you find a program in an area you find particularly interesting. Enjoy your graduate studies, then think about jobs.

Your undergraduate studies suggest you'll be OK in grad school.

Comment: If I want to find an cs-related job, will an Msc or PhD in applied math help?

Comment: @Euler'slittlehelper Only a small fraction of cs-related jobs call for applied mathematics.

Comment: Since I will have a Bsc in cs, does the major I choose in grad school really matter?

Comment: Matter for what? You can't really get this kind of advice anonymously from people who don't know you. That's why the question was closed. I think you should study something you want to know more about. Good luck.